# How run a command with windows task schedular with arguments

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to schedule a task that for each file in a specific local directory deletes a file with the same name on a remote server's directory.

On the command I run this

```
for  %f in (*) do start winscp /command "open ftp://user:password@mythost.com/"   "rm %f" "close" "exit"
```

and it works

but when I run it as a scheduled task and starting the `cmd.exe` program and passing in the following argument `for  %f in (*) do start winscp  /command "open ftp://user:pass@host.com/"   "rm %f" "close" "exit"` it doesnt work

what is my problem?

Comment: 'it doesn't work" - Can you be more specific?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command works from command line, but not from Task Scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/629554/command-works-from-command-line-but-not-from-task-scheduler)

Comment: Please kindly check if the following thread was helpful to you:[How to pass an argument to a Windows Scheduled Task with spaces in it](https://superuser.com/questions/270643/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-windows-scheduled-task-with-spaces-in-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "/c" at the beginning of the arguments:

```
/c for  %f in (*) do start winscp  /command "open ftp://user:pass@host.com/"   "rm %f" "close" "exit"
```

So the complete command would become as follows:

```
cmd.exe /c for  %f in (*) do start winscp  /command "open ftp://user:pass@host.com/"   "rm %f" "close" "exit"
```

For more details, see also this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5047185/5538923 .

Comment: Good, but now I scheduled the task. Each time the task runs it opens a cmd promp window. Can I stop this? @marcor92

Comment: @Meilech in order not to show the cmd prompt window, you can try to remove the "/command" from your arguments. For more details see here: https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10977 and here: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting .